# How to set an application language by URI path segment using Catberry framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, frameworks, isomorphic-javascript

For example, I use [catberry-l10n](https://github.com/catberry/catberry-l10n) plugin I'd like to define the application's language like this:

```
www.example.com/en
www.example.com/de
www.example.com/ru
```

Answer (score 2):

So, the described approach is very easy to implement in your project using Catberry's routing rules and adding `LocaleStore` that takes locale parameter from the URI. The store data can be used by any other stores without performance impact.

For example, you have such route rule:

```
module.exports = [
  '/:locale[LocaleStore]/somecrazysegment'
];
```

Also, you have LocaleStore:

```
LocaleStore.prototype.load = function () {
  // here can be a profile's language request or something else
  return this.$context.state.locale;
};
```

So, we have LocaleStore and now we can use it.

```
SomeStore.prototype.load = function () {
  return Promise.all([
    this.$context.getStoreData('LocaleStore'),
    this._uhr.get('http://api.some.org/data')
  ])
    .then(function (results) {
      return {
        locale: results[0],
        obj: results[1]
      };
    });
};
```

After that, you can use such data in your component like it was in the [example](https://github.com/catberry/catberry-l10n#how-to-use):

```
Component.prototype.render = function () {
  var self = this;
  return this.$context.getStoreData()
    .then(function (data) {
       return {
         localizedEat: self._l10n.get(data.locale, 'EAT'),
         localizedApple: util.format(
           self._l10n.pluralize(data.locale, 'APPLE', data.obj.appleCount),
           appleCount
         )
       };
   });
};
```